# I am not able to upload image in openshift using nodejs

Tags: node.js, openshift, multer

These codes are working well in local environment but when I pushed to openshift it's  notworking in Openshift I have also find that to use "process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR" for getting image's uploaded path but i cant get the desired result it's undefined and here is my code, I am totally new in this case so please help with demo one so i easily understand the process.Thanks

```
    // set storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination:'./public/uploads',
  filename: function(req,file,cb){
    cb(null,file.fieldname + '-' +Date.now() +
      path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

    // Init upload
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage
}).single('myImage');



////////  post route for upload images
app.post('/adsupload',(req,res)=>{
   console.log("detail before saving"+req.file)
  upload(req, res, (err) =>{
    if(err){
      res.render('imageupload',{
        msg: err
      });
    } else if(req.file== undefined){
     res.render('imageupload',{
      msg:'Error: No file selected'
     });
    }else{
      console.log("detail before saving"+req.file)
      var dirName = process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR;
      console.log('dirname'+dirName)
      console.log('dirname2'+OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR);// these are undefined

      var ads = new Ads({
        ads_name: req.file.filename,
        ads_path: path.join(__dirname+'./public/uploads/'+req.file.filename)

      })
      ads.save().then((doc)=>{
    // res.send(doc)
    console.log('image saved in database')
  },(e)=>{
    // req.status(400).send(e)
    console.log('error while saving image in database'+err)
  });
      console.log('getting filename'+ req.file.filename);
      res.render('imageupload',{
        msg: 'File Uploaded',
        file: 'uploads/'+req.file.filename
      });
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: I am not familiar with OpenShift, but it looks like you need to create OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR as an environment variable in the container

Answer (score 1):

OpenShift 3 doesn't provide a persistent data directory for you as a default like OpenShift 2 did. You will need to claim a persistent volume and mount it into your application at some directory. You should then set `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` in the deployment config for your application to tell it where you mounted your data directory.